# Ionic Tinder Cards 2 - Too many cards in card array breaks card stack view

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

Currently I am using Ionic Tinder Cards 2 in a project. This is the Github page for it: [Ionic Tinder Cards 2](https://github.com/loringdodge/ionic-ion-tinder-cards-2)

The problem I have is this: When I add too many cards to the *active cards* array (The array of cards which should be displayed in the HTML view), the card stack breaks. I have made a Codepen which hopefully explains this better: [Codepen for the "breaking" example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGYYYd)

If you, in this codepen, just try to slighty drag the first card in the stack, you will see what I mean. It's as if, when the stack gets too long, it will start to get mirroed in the bottom.

I'm not sure what code in the Ionic plugin causes this, but I have attempted to fix this problem by attempting to just show a subset of the overall array. That is, instead of trying to load in all 30 images I have, I just want to show 10 of them at a time. I attempted to do this through Angular like this:

```
<div ng-if="cards.active">
<td-cards>
    <td-card ng-repeat="card in cards.active|limitTo:9" on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)" on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)" on-swipe-right="cardSwipedRight($index)">
        <div class="image">

            <div class="no-text"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></div>
            <div class="yes-text"><i class="icon_circle-empty"></i></div>

            <img ng-src="{{ card.image }}">
        </div>
    </td-card>
    <td-card id="end-card" drag="false">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-close"></i>
    </td-card>
</td-cards>
```

That is, by attempting to set a "limitTo" modifier so that only 9 cards are displayed at a time from the card array (it seems that it breaks when you go above 9 cards). Unfortunately, this seems to bring the problem that the swipe functionality just stops working as soon as you start getting to the cards above the 9 index mark. It's as if this kind of dynamic work with the card array just does not work at all.

If anyone is interested, this is the Javascript I use in the Ionic Controller for adding cards to the "active cards" array:

```
var poemCardStack = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("unlikedPoems"));

$scope.cards = {
master: Array.prototype.slice.call(poemCardStack, 0),
active: Array.prototype.slice.call(poemCardStack, 0),
discards: [],
liked: [],
disliked: []
}
```

I simply load an array of image file paths to the array and link it to the "active" cards array. This part I know works.

The question then is, how will I either fix this mirroring problem so that even with big arrays, the card stack will just continue to fade to the background, or how can I show only a subset at a time of the overall array?

Thank you all for your help :)